# Tabs : data-toggle doesn't expand data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to toggle my table html array but it doesn't work.

If I display text like 'toto' or 'titi' instead of table array html it works.
I use a specific framework (mantisbt) so I don't have choice to have tabs server-side on php.

I am using bootstrap3.

[image: Illustration pictures]

Here the code :

```
echo '<tr class="no-padding tab" colspan="6">';
echo '<th class="Category">  </th>';
echo '<td class="Category" colspan="5">

<div id="exTab1" class="container">
<ul  class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active">
        <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">TAB 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">TAB 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">TAB 3</a>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">TAB 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

  </div>

</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo'<div class="tab-content clearfix">
<div class="tab-pane" id="1a">

<tr class="no-padding tab" colspan="6">
    <th class="Category">  Titre 1 </th>

    <td class="Category" colspan="5">

            Champs 1

    </td>
</tr>
</div>


<div class="tab-pane"  id="2a">

<tr class="no-padding tab" colspan="6">
    <th class="Category">  Titre 2 </th>

    <td class="Category" colspan="5">

Champs 2

    </td>
</tr>

</div>';
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to “toggle”. Further, although there are some `echo` statements, is the toggling a client side thing or a server side thing?

Comment: What are you using for your data-toggle to activate?  Looks like bootstrap-5, but please confirm.

Comment: Hello, @ChrisHaas & freedomn-m thanks for your anwsers.  1) Yes, you are right maybe at first, I should test on basic html/js like codepen if it's work before I implement on my tool; 2) Yes it's bootstrap 3